# APK Icon Editor - APKTool Error

Tags: android

I tried simply changing icons and the name of an APK and it gives me an "APKTool Error" message. I don't know what the problem is, I'm still new to Android, but any help would be appreciated. Here's the log from when I opened the app to where the error message appears.

```
[21:04:12.687] 
--- Packing APK ---
[21:04:12.687] Output file: "/Users/user/Documents/All Docs/Web Design and Business Management/Vulture TV/VultureTV.apk"
[21:04:12.687] Contents directory: "/Users/user/Documents/All Docs/Web Design and Business Management/Vulture TV/apk-icon-editor//apk/"
[21:04:12.687] New application title: "Vulture TV"
[21:04:12.687] New version code: "5"
[21:04:12.688] New version name: "Final"
[21:04:12.688] Using Apktool: true
[21:04:12.688] Smali: false
[21:04:12.688] Sign: true
[21:04:12.688] Zipalign: true
[21:04:12.688] Using KeyStore: true
[21:04:12.688] KeyStore found;
[21:04:12.688] KeyStore Password: present;
[21:04:12.688] Alias: "Vulture TV"
[21:04:12.688] Alias Password: present;
[21:04:14.872] "W: res/drawable-mdpi-v4/ic_perfect_player_banner copy.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-zA-Z0-9_.]\nException in thread \"main\" brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec (exit code = 1): [aapt, p, --forced-package-id, 127, --min-sdk-version, 14, --target-sdk-version, 23, --version-code, 5, --version-name, Final, --no-version-vectors, -F, /var/folders/zr/yvgvy8510l71wkx18y7ck5ww0000gn/T/APKTOOL14150718005616826268.tmp, -0, arsc, -I, /Users/user/Documents/All Docs/Web Design and Business Management/Vulture TV/apk-icon-editor/framework/1.apk, -S, /Users/user/Documents/All Docs/Web Design and Business Management/Vulture TV/apk-icon-editor/apk/res, -M, /Users/user/Documents/All Docs/Web Design and Business Management/Vulture TV/apk-icon-editor/apk/AndroidManifest.xml]\n\tat brut.androlib.Androlib.buildResourcesFull(Androlib.java:477)\n\tat brut.androlib.Androlib.buildResources(Androlib.java:411)\n\tat brut.androlib.Androlib.build(Androlib.java:310)\n\tat brut.androlib.Androlib.build(Androlib.java:263)\n\tat brut.apktool.Main.cmdBuild(Main.java:227)\n\tat brut.apktool.Main.main(Main.java:84)\nCaused by: brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec (exit code = 1): [aapt, p, --forced-package-id, 127, --min-sdk-version, 14, --target-sdk-version, 23, --version-code, 5, --version-name, Final, --no-version-vectors, -F, /var/folders/zr/yvgvy8510l71wkx18y7ck5ww0000gn/T/APKTOOL14150718005616826268.tmp, -0, arsc, -I, /Users/user/Documents/All Docs/Web Design and Business Management/Vulture TV/apk-icon-editor/framework/1.apk, -S, /Users/user/Documents/All Docs/Web Design and Business Management/Vulture TV/apk-icon-editor/apk/res, -M, /Users/user/Documents/All Docs/Web Design and Business Management/Vulture TV/apk-icon-editor/apk/AndroidManifest.xml]\n\tat brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.aaptPackage(AndrolibResources.java:440)\n\tat brut.androlib.Androlib.buildResourcesFull(Androlib.java:463)\n\t... 5 more\nCaused by: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec (exit code = 1): [aapt, p, --forced-package-id, 127, --min-sdk-version, 14, --target-sdk-version, 23, --version-code, 5, --version-name, Final, --no-version-vectors, -F, /var/folders/zr/yvgvy8510l71wkx18y7ck5ww0000gn/T/APKTOOL14150718005616826268.tmp, -0, arsc, -I, /Users/user/Documents/All Docs/Web Design and Business Management/Vulture TV/apk-icon-editor/framework/1.apk, -S, /Users/user/Documents/All Docs/Web Design and Business Management/Vulture TV/apk-icon-editor/apk/res, -M, /Users/user/Documents/All Docs/Web Design and Business Management/Vulture TV/apk-icon-editor/apk/AndroidManifest.xml]\n\tat brut.util.OS.exec(OS.java:95)\n\tat brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.aaptPackage(AndrolibResources.java:434)\n\t... 6 more\n"
[21:04:14.872] Error (): Apktool Error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove space in the png name
"ic_perfect_player_banner copy.png"

Comment: Have you removed in all the drawable folders?

Comment: Yes, it was just the one that had that image, it's not even a necessity, so I deleted it.